# Cakephp: Associations not working

Tags: cakephp

I want to do a simple cakephp association program but it's not working.
I have two database tables: `users` and `sec_datas`. When i run this program it just shows the result of first row of `users` table, not the result of both tables which have same `sec_id` value.

Controller code:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function  index()
    {
        $this->autoRender = FALSE;
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $storeDivisions = $this->User->find();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($storeDivisions);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Model code:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $useTable='users';

    public $hasOne = array(
        'Sec_data' => array(
            'ClassName' => 'Sec_data',
            'Conditions' => array('User.sec_id=Sec_data.sec_id'),
            'Dependent' => false
        )
    );  
}
?>
```

Comment: For starters, your `hasOne` array keys should be lowercase.

Comment: There's a lot wrong/weird/unconventional here. Why does the model class name have an underscore in it? Putting an underscore in the model alias (The association array key) makes it basically inaccessible. You don't show the executed queries - are you asking for `Sec_data` records but finding none? There's no containable or recursive information - are you not asking for associated records at all? Is User _actually_ your model class or an AppModel instance? In summary: **Does it work being conventional**?

Comment: you have to pass $this->User->recursive = 2; before $storeDivisions = $this->User->find();

Answer (score 1):

If the primary key of User model is `id` then cake try to associate the foreign key in Sec_data with that key regardless the conditions you set.

First of all you should do domething like

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Sec_data' => array(
        'ClassName' => 'Sec_data',
        'ForeignKey' => 'sec_id',
        'Dependent' => false
    )
);
```

But it would work only if `sec_id` is related to `User.id`

<strike>if you want Sec_data.sec_id related to User.sec_id (and User.sec_id is different from User.id) then you have to join the tables manually</strike>

edit: see comments

Comment: It'd be necessary to set foreign key to false _and_ define conditions to achieve `the result of both tables which have same sec_id value` via an association definition. It is not true that a manual join is required.

Comment: thanks @AD7six. Can you please link the part of the official documentation where this is explained?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going wrong here. You should read up on CakePHP's conventions.

- Your associated model class should be called `SecData`, then it will automatically map to the `sec_datas` table.
- No need to use `loadModel`.
- No need to specify conditions. Set the correct `recursive` level instead.
- For `hasOne`, only one table has a foreign key. By default, the other Model has it ("User hasOne SecData" -> SecData has foreign key). So in your example, you should remove the column `sec_id` from `User`, and add a `user_id` column to your `SecData` Model.

See also: [CakePHP Book on associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone)

Updated Controller code:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('User'); // Do this instead of loadModel

    public function  index() {
        $this->autoRender = FALSE;

        $this->User->recursive = 1; // Make User load associated records
        $storeDivisions = $this->User->find('all');
        pr($storeDivisions); // pr() is a Cake shorthand for print_r wrapped in <pre>
    }
}
```

For your model:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    // Unecessary. Convention is to use lowercase classname + 's', which
    // already gives us 'users'
    // public $useTable='users'; 

    public $hasOne = array(
        'SecData' => array( // Model class Sec_Data must be renamed accordingly
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Study model association in cake php . Here is very good explanation http://www.phpsupercoder.com/model-association-cake-php